# Is there any way to change between Blazor components automatically?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to change between Blazor components (e.g. Home and Counter) in an automatic way every one minute.

I have tried to look for triggers or flags giving parameters but have found nothing. If anyone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

PD. I'm new to all this Blazor topic.

Comment: I am not sure I get what is your purpose, but I guess you could set a `Timer` in `OnInitializedAsync` and in the handler call `NavigationManager`. The best way would probably to put this code in a Blazor component having the next page as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example demonstrating how to use a timer and the `DynamicComponent`.  To use multiple components you'll need to iterate through a list.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<DynamicComponent Type="_currentComponent" />

@code {
    private Type _currentComponent = typeof(Counter);
    private bool _switch;
    private System.Threading.Timer? _timer;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _timer = new Timer(this.TimerEvent, null, 3000, 3000);
    }

    private void TimerEvent(object? statw)
    {
        if (_switch)
            _currentComponent = typeof(Counter);
        else
            _currentComponent = typeof(Weather);

        this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        _switch = !_switch;
    }
}
```